# How to fetch binaries a package will install?

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, command-line, 13.04, 16.04

Given a package name that is not installed (binutils is installed and binutils-gold is not in my case), how to figure out what binaries it is going to install?

```
dpkg -l binutils*
```

Above lists out both and says binutils is installed but binutils-gold is not.

```
dpkg -L binutils
```

Above lists out all binaries or atleast all files binutils installs in your system. I want to query similarly binutils-gold before installing it and same for some other packages.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a very helpful package: `apt-file` (that you have to install first, and then `apt-file update` to fetch the list of files)

```
apt-file list binutils-gold
```

will list the files provided by that.

It has also many more helpful features, like a `search`, to look for a package that provides a file that you need.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work for me. it does not show details for uninstalled packages.

Comment: That package `binutils-gold` in the repositories is just a virtual package, so it does not contain any file. The "idea" is that some packages depend on this `binutils-gold`, but all its functionality are in `binutils`, so `binutils` "declares" **I am** `binutils-gold`. If you do not refer to the one in the official repositories, there might be some other problems, so please specify from which repo your are picking it. Look at [this manual](http://people.canonical.com/~cjwatson/ubuntu-policy/policy.html/ch-relationships.html#s-virtual) for more info.